# Swift grammar explicit member expression

Tags: swift, generics, grammar

In the [grammar section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) of the Swift book there are two grammar declarations:

```
explicit-member-expression  ->  postfix-expression  .  decimal-digits
explicit-member-expression  ->  postfix-expression  .  identifier  generic-argument-clause[opt]
```

The first one is used for accessing tuples:

```
var tuple = (1, 2, 3)
tuple.1 = tuple.2
```

The second one is used for accessing other members like properties and functions:

```
struct S {
    var property = 0
    func function<T>(parameter: T) {}
}

S().property
S().function(3)
```

However I couldn't find a use for the optional `generic-argument-clause`. It is prohibited after those members:

```
S().property<Int>   // error: '>' is not a postfix unary operator
S().function<Int>(3) // error: cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
```

**So in which case can we use the `generic-argument-clause`s?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Generic argument clauses for member expressions of modules

It is possible that the `generic-argument-clause` only has a use case for *modules* (`SomeModule.SomeGeneric<SomeType>()`). From the [Language Reference - Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html):

> **Explicit Member Expression**
>
> An explicit member expression allows access to the members of a named
>   type, a tuple, **or a module**. It consists of a period (.) between the
>   item and the identifier of its member.

As an example:

```
/* Module 'MyLib.a' ... */
class MyClass<T> {
    var foo: T?
}

/* ... elsewhere: explicit member expression to module */
MyLib.MyClass<Int>()
```

Curiously enough, [*implicit* member expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) includes no grammar for `generic-argument-clause[opt]`, which we can interpret as an implicit cursor that the latter, for explicit member expressions, does not concern, at the very least, enumerations; possibly slightly boosting the theory that this only concerns modules.

> *Grammar Of A Implicit Member Expression*
>
> ```
> implicit-member-expression → .­identifier­
> ```

---

## Other use cases, beyond that of modules?

I can't say for sure that the above is applicable only for modules, but I haven't been able to find any other uses of generic argument clauses in the context of member expressions.

Below follows some relevant reference extracts in a somewhat discussive context; it can perhaps hold some value for others' investigation into this, beyond that of modules.

---

First of all, what is a generic argument clause? From [Language Reference - Generic Parameters and Arguments - Generic Argument Clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html)

> A generic argument clause specifies the *type arguments of a generic type.*
>
> ...
>
> The generic argument list is a comma-separated list of type arguments.
>   A type argument is the name of an actual concrete type that replaces a
>   corresponding type parameter in the generic parameter clause of a
>   generic type. The result is a specialized version of that generic
>   type.
>
> ...
>
> The specialized version of the generic `Dictionary` type,
>   `Dictionary<String, Int>` is formed by replacing the generic
>   parameters `Key: Hashable` and `Value` with the concrete type
>   arguments `String` and `Int`.

Now, the same section wraps up with the following statement:

> As mentioned in *Generic Parameter Clause*, **you don’t use a generic
>   argument clause to specify the type arguments of a generic function**
>   or initializer.

We jump to the *Generic Parameter Clause* section and read:

> ... **In contrast with generic types**, you don’t specify a generic
>   argument clause when you use a generic function or initializer. The
>   type arguments are instead inferred from the type of the arguments
>   passed to the function or initializer.

So for the subject of this question, we should focus on the combination of *member expressions* and (for the right hand side of the `.`) *generic types*; not generic functions. But in what context---in addition to modules---can we combine these two and generic arguments clauses? The first that might come to mind is an `enum` with an associated generic type:

```
enum Bar<T> {
    case One(T)
    case Two
}

var foo = Bar.One(1)
print(foo.dynamicType) // Bar<Int>
```

But this is type inference, not generic argument clauses.

---

From the above, I can only think of modules as the use case for grammar `generic-argument-clause` in the context of member expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately accessing generic types in modules is a `type-identifier`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Comment: This is true, but in my example I'm accessing an initializer and not the type itself (a bit unclear, `MyLib.MyClass<Int>()`); would it still be considered a type identifier? E.g., `MyLib.MyClass<Int>().foo` <-- the "middle" member expression seemingly contains a generic argument clause (and is an instance, not a type here).

Comment: (As an example, compare `let typeIdentifier = UIKit.UIView // UIView.Type` with `let memberExpression = UIKit.UIView() // UIView instance` or `anotherMemberExpression = UIKit.UIView().alpha // 1 (CGFloat)`)

Comment: Good theory. Clearly we need to cross reference the grammar with the Swift.org source...

Comment: Ah yeah. So this should be (semantically) an initializer-expression however grammar wise it isn't: (`postfix-expression  .  init`). I think it is a function-call-expression!? (On the `init`)

Comment: I'll leave this for another day/tomorrow, CET calls me (too late) to bed. Good luck with the night-grammar!